# How to segregate turtles in NetLogo in a specific region

Tags: netlogo

Is it possibile, in NetLogo, to create a sort of fenced area (corral) in which I can isolate n sick turtles (not unlimited) while sane turtles can't access it? 
If yes, how can I move sick turtles there? And how can I prevent sane turtles from getting there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i've done is isolating a bunch of patches.

Say your origin point is in the center of your frame. And your `max-xcor` is 30 and your `max-ycor` is 30 too.

Take this map as a reference.

[image: NetLogo workspace]

Say now that sick turtles must be in the first quadrant and healthy turtles must be in the third quadrant.

You want to `ask` `turtles with` sick status to `face` the upper right corner. This would be coordinates (30,30)  then they should check if they are in the designated area. If not, keep moving forward. Since you want them to segregate around the first quadrant you want to make a procedure to **make them move randomly once they're in there**.

Same goes for healthy turtles, ask them to `face` coordinates -30,-30 and then `ask` them to go `forward` a random number of steps, then they should check if they are in the designated area. If not, keep moving forward.

- How to prevent sick turtles from getting in sick turtle's area?

Ask every healthy turtle which their coordinates are, if these coordinates are very close to sick turtle's area, make them face the other way (say random coords).

- How to know if they're very close to sick turtle's?

With an if!

```
Ifelse [turtles.coordinateX + 5 >= 30 && turtle.coordinateY + 5 >= 30] [true][false] < This means they're close by 5 patches!
```

Rewrite that in netlogo of course.

There's a lot of help here too. http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/

Comment: The problem with this approach is the the program will have to contain lots of these tests. It would be very much easier by just naming a `patch-set`

Answer (score 0):

This could be more simple way of doing the same I think,

```
First design the quadrants during setup :


ask patches with [ pxcor <= max-pxcor and pxcor > 0  and pycor > 0]
  [
    set pcolor red
    set quadrant 1

  ]

  ask patches with [ pxcor >= min-pxcor and pxcor < 0  and pycor > 0]
  [
    set pcolor blue
    set quadrant 2
  ]

  ask patches with [ pxcor <= max-pxcor and pxcor > 0  and pycor < 0]
  [
    set pcolor green
    set quadrant 3
  ]

  ask patches with [ pxcor >= min-pxcor and pxcor < 0  and pycor < 0]
  [
    set pcolor yellow
    set quadrant 4
  ]
Now on 'go'
to go
  ask turtles with [gender = "Female"] [
    let p one-of patches with [quadrant = 1]
    move-to p
  ]
  ask turtles with [gender = "Male"] [
    let p one-of patches with [quadrant = 4]
    move-to p
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create a `patch-set` and label it hospital. To do this, you need:

```
globals [hospital]

to setup
  ....
  set hospital patches with [pxcor < -10 and pycor < -10 ]
  ...
end
```

Then any time you have turtles move, you can get the turtle to refer to the hospital. For example:

```
ask turtles
[ face one-of hospital
  forward 1
]
```

Or you can jump to a random `patch` that's not in the hospital:

```
ask turtles [ move-to one-of patches with [not member? self hospital ]]
```

Here's a complete model that puts this together:

```
globals [hospital]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 20
  set hospital patches with [pxcor < -10 and pycor < -10 ]
  ask hospital [set pcolor red]
  ask turtles
  [ move-to one-of patches with [not member? self hospital]
  ]
end
```